# Downgrade Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We have a A6 Standard VM, since we are not really use it, we want to downgrade it to A3 Basic VM.

Currently, on the server (A6), we have SQL server installed, and we have a data disk, different programs are installed on it. We want to keep all the disks, so will not lose any data.

It seems all we need to do is: change the VM size from control panel. Anyone did the similar work before? I want to make sure we will not lose any data.

Comment: How many data disk do you have in your virtual machine?

Comment: This type of question belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: the DATA DISK is 1TB.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The only data you may lose will be that on your Temp drive (which you shouldn't be using for any persistent data anyway).  Your data disks will be safe, and A3 supports 8 disks the same as A6, so all will be good.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of promoting SQL Azure Database and pricing differences here. The question is specifically  about VM downsizing and the implications of potential data loss.

Same thing about the single-instance SLA point. Not relevant.

Comment: Hence the "as an aside" statement - thought it could be helpful since most people consider downsizing to save money, and would therefore be relevant, but I see your point, maybe I should just refer the op to the azure docs and we let bots answer the questions :-)

Comment: Yes, the main reason for downgrade is for saving cost since we are not using this instance much now. But we do not want to lose any data.

Comment: @urlreader - if you want to save money & be more cost effective, I'd highly recommend you look to see if you can move your SQL database to SQL Azure (PaaS), and your application to App Services. If you're currently paying around $200 per month for the VM, and maybe need 2 instances to make it resilient ($400), you could get the same kind of hosting in App Services and SQL Azure for around $40, with more resilience, availability, and lots of features built in like point in time restore, automatic backups, auto scale. It's a no brainer and most apps can be moved really easily.

Comment: @RussellYoung - Just keeping things honest here: $40 for web app + SQL Database? That'll get you a shared-tier web app + S1 SQL Database instance (and you're comparing that to a dedicated multi-core VM). I think it's very misleading comparing such a low-tier offering to a full VM. Until you do benchmarks, this comparison doesn't make sense, and is definitely not a **no brainer.** Things get even trickier if the OP is using features not supported directly in SQL Database service.